# Hibernate Query, how to group different tables?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

Im pretty new to databases, and programming in general, i tried everything but could not come up with a solution, my problem is:
I have 2 tables in my database:

- Cars
- Model

in my Cars table i have 3 columns:
*modelID
*carName
*carsSold

and the Model table has 3 columns:
*modelID
*modelName
*modelYear

Now my program has a button that says Group by Model, when the user clicks it has to show the information grouped by the Model, like:

1. Model ID : 1022

   - Model Name: Audi
   - Car Name: A3
   - Year: 2001
   - Cars sold: 120

Everything is ready, im just lost at the HQL query

Comment: What, if any, type of relation mapping are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some problems with your database schema.

What is the primary key for car? What is the mapping relationship between car and model?

The way it reads, you have two tables with info such as:

```
CAR
modelID | carName | carsSold
----------------------------
1022    | A3    | 120

MODEL
modelID | modelName | modelYear
-------------------------------
1022    | Audi      | 2001
```

This does not seem like a logical arrangement for the data you are trying to represent.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. I'm also not sure that "group by" is what you are looking for.

If this is really your entire database structure, and you are not planning anything else, why not have one table? table SALE(id, modelName, carName, modelYear, carsSold) or something like that.  With this table, the HQL is simply a select and then display the information from the model object.

Maybe if you clarified what the requirements are for your data I could give you some better direction on where to go with your database.

Comment: thanks, i just got help from a friend and was able to come up with the SQL sintax, now i need to do this in HQL:SELECT modeloID, nomeCarro, anoDeFabricacao, marcaDoModelo 
FROM Carros JOIN Modelo 
ON Carros.modeloID = Modelo.modeloID
GROUP BY modeloID;

Comment: GROUP BY modeloID does not make sense, unless there is some kind of mapping in your database that I am completely missing, and I still don't think your schema is set up correctly. As described, you would not need the group by in this case, the join would accomplish the same thing.  I can't help with a Hibernate query until I have more info on your hibernate mappings.